# How to alter the uc_address:city form field?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have to alter cities form field in checkout page under delivery section. I have to change it from a textfield to a select options dropdown.

- I have managed to do that using a separate template file for checkout page but I
  am not able to use `#ajax` functionality of form field
- In Drupal 6 it was possible using `hook_form_uc_cart_checkout_form_alter()`, but in Drupal 7 the address fields are rendered in a different way, and I'm not able to alter the address form fields as desired

What are other ways of changing it?

I used `hook_form_alter()` with an `#after_build` callback; I was able to change the field from text field to select option, but the `#ajax` parameter attached to this is not working.

It seems like ajax callbacks are attached with the hooks at an early stage. Is there any way to have the #ajax property working?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Addressfield](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module you can easily do that extending the module itself.

Look into the **`sites/all/modules/addressfield/plugin/format`** & you will see `address.inc`, where you can extend the list of region or city.

You can look for the example in **`sites/all/modules/addressfield/example/plugin/format`** to better understanding of the the format which module will accept for extending it for your list values.

Comment: I am using ubercart. There is address.inc at path modules\ubercart\uc_store\classes\ but this looks more like a class definition. Here is the reference to this class http://drupalcode.org/project/ubercart.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/uc_store/classes/address.inc.

Comment: @mjs Can't help then. Sorry...I don't have experience with ubercart but only Drupal Commerce. I saw you mentioning addressfield, so thought may be they also addressfield for taking address from users..

Comment: Files that comes with a module or Drupal should never be changed; the problem would be updating the module or Drupal.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Yes I understand. But if somebody has to do list the region name, or some values list for some particular country, they can open a issue, do it and submit the patch. Contributors will happily accept that..I have done the same.